# Чёрный экран при установке

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня стоит Windows 7, сейчас мне нужно поставить Linux Ubuntu. Я записал образ на DVD диск, после загрузки компьютера с диска появляются пиктограммы Ubuntu, затем появляется чёрный экран с мигающим курсором, в конце концов компьютер намертво повисает.

Что я делаю не так при установке Ubuntu?

Comment: Другой образ? С оф сайта например?

Comment: @ReinRaus Скачено с официального сайта.Я скачивал уже несколько раз.

Comment: Предыдущие версии попробуйте. Попробуйте записать образ на флэшку.

Comment: Возможно просто диск повреждён — попробуйте через флэшку.

Answer (score 2):

> появляются пиктограммы Ubuntu,затем появляется чёрный экран с мигающим курсором

предполагаю, что всё вы правильно делаете, просто не запускается [x-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

для проверки во время «мигания курсора на чёрном фоне» переключитесь на первый/второй виртуальный терминал (<kbd>alt+ctrl+f1</kbd>/<kbd>alt+ctrl+f2</kbd>) — если увидите картинку типа этой:

[image: login screen]

значит, так оно и есть. дальше уже надо разбираться, что именно «не нравится» x-серверу — анализировать содержимое лог-файла `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

с совсем начальными знаниями это проделать, конечно, сложновато, потому в качестве «а вдруг получится» я бы порекомендовал для начала попробовать загрузить систему с [параметром *nomodeset*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#line-72).

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что иксам не нравится конкретно это железо. Полностью согласен.

Comment: @Ancient, это не вы, случайно, за последние полчаса поставили уже 4 «плюса» моим ответам? будьте внимательны: движок сайта может посчитать эти голоса «накруткой» и «откатить» их.